# Cypher: multiple relationship types directed and undirected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to make a cypher query which includes two alternative types, but one of it is directed and one isn't. Is there a simple way to express this in cypher?

e.g. 
a -INHERITANCE-> b (directed)

x -EQUIVALENT- y (undirected)

Give me all nodes which n inherits or is equal to.

MATCH (n)-[INHERITANCE|EQUIVALENT *]-(n2) doesn't consider the directed characteristic of INHERITANCE

Answer (score 3):

Basically I see two approaches to that:

1. use Cypher's [`UNION`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-union.html) statement and join the results of the two matches
2. run the match undirected and filter out the unwated matches using a where filter:

.

```
MATCH (a)-[r:INHERTIANCE|:EQUIVALENT]-(b)
WHERE type(r)="EQUIVALENT" OR endNode(r)=b
...
```

Just symbolic code above, have not tested it.

Comment: this is a pretty nice idea! is this still applicable for a variable length path (*) ?

Comment: should work as well, however you have to [apply predicates (all/none)](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-predicates.html) instead of a single comparison.

Comment: a different approach would be to model `EQUIVALENT` in both directions (aka 2 relationships different direction). Then you could do simply do a directed match to get correct results.